# Flink SQL Unit Testing: How to Assign Watermark?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-table-api

I'm writing a unit test for a Flink SQL statement that uses match_recognize. I'm setting up the test data like this

```
Table data = tEnv.fromValues(DataTypes.ROW(
  DataTypes.FIELD("event_time", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3)),
  DataTypes.FIELD("foobar", DataTypes.STRING()),
  ....
  ),
  row(...),
  row(...)
);
```

I have two questions,

- How do I designate event_time as the field for watermarking? (indicating rowtime)
- Less important, give the table created a meaningful name?

FLINK VERSION: 1.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit a current limitation of the Table API: it's not possible to define watermarks and rowtime attributes in combination with the `forValues` method; you need a connector. There are a couple of options to work around it:

**1.** Use a `csv` connector that you stack up with your `VALUES`, like shown in [this example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/4ccc07b606b8bc121576b45aa6684c0c71a911f5/flink-examples/flink-examples-table/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/examples/java/basics/UpdatingTopCityExample.java).

**2.** Use the built-in [DataGen connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/datagen.html). Since you're putting together a unit test for CEP, I imagine that you want some degree of control over the data that is generated, so this is probably not a viable option. Thought I'd mention it, anyways.

**Note:** Using SQL DDL syntax is the recommended way to create tables from Flink 1.10. This would make both things you're trying to do (*i.e.* defining a watermark and naming your table) more straightforward:

```java
tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE table_name (\n" +
                "             event_time TIMESTAMP(3),\n" +
                "             foobar STRING \n" +
                "             WATERMARK FOR event_time AS event_time\n" +
                ") WITH (...)"
);

Table data = tEnv.from("table_name");
```

The watermark is declared as a *computed column* and there are multiple watermark strategies you can opt to use. Please check [this documentation page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/sql/create.html) for more details.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your response.